# present prompt for get-csuser -Identity

Tags: powershell-3.0, skype-for-business

I'm trying to write a PS script to make it easier to find accounts by simply adding in the Identity of the user.

The idea is to allow other S4B admins to grant recording policy for users with a basic powershell script.  SOme of our admins don't know anything about PS and i'm must learning myself.

I have this code that I use - `Get-csuser -Identity "email here" |Grant-CsConferencingPolicy -PolicyName "AllowRecording"`

What i'm looking to do, but have yet to find in my google searching, is a way to prompt for the Identity.  So the other admins will run the script, a prompt in PS will say something like Email address of User:  They'll add the email, hit enter, and the policy will be granted by the script.

That's where i'm stuck.  How do i get the prompt, and get that input added into the script to grant the policy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$UserEmail = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input the user email'
Grant-CsConferencingPolicy -identity $UserEmail -PolicyName "AllowRecording"
```

Explanation:

1. Read host  will perform a prompt, the information entered here is saved in the UsersEmail variable (see [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176935.aspx) for more info's)
2. The users email variable is then used to grant the policy to the user (see [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg425937.aspx) for more info's)

Comment: Perfect!  that's what i was looking for.